# SEO Friendly URLs when developing with HTML 5 & JSON for "Run Anywhere"

Tags: json, html, seo, friendly-url

I'm just starting out on a WORA project: Front end: HTML5 / JSON; Back end: .NET MVC API.

I'm looking for some pointers on how to develop so that the site has SEO friendly URLS.

Obviously this is fine if the front end is .NET as you can use Global.ASAX or Rewrite in web.config, but if the front end is simple HTML5 and JSON to allow for deployment as mobile web and native apps then the structure has to be generated in the javascript or HTML.

Are there any tutorials/articles out there on how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to the `.htaccess` files? (No pun intended).

You can use rewrite rules there too for clean urls. One example is [here](http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/web-servers/36500-create-clean-url-htaccess-rewrite-engine.html).

Comment: Don't know yet.  Am still developing in localhost.  Up til know I've always used .NET functionality for redirects, but in moving to JSON and HTML5 just wanted some pointers for alternatives.  Will look into .htaccess option.  Thanks.